# rainloop curl not downloading

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

I'm trying to install [Rainloop](https://www.rainloop.net/) on my server.
In the documentation its sayed to download rainloop via the curl command
"curl -s https://repository.rainloop.net/installer.php | php".
When I enter this command nothing happens. And if I enter the command without the "-s" it only shows this:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>
> 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

It looks like the download won't even start. Since there is no error message I don't know what the error is.

Some technical Infos:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Lamp stack is installed
Dovecot etc. also

Thanks for possible replys.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was just too stupid :)
I missed some dependencies. After that everything worked fine.